# Is Android OpenSSL build configuration armv7 safe for all arm devices?

Tags: android, android-ndk, openssl

I am currently in the process of updating our project OpenSSL to 1.0.1i using http://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/Android.

Looking in the config file I found that OpenSSL has 2 Android build options: android-armv7 and android-x86.

I have been able to build the armv7 configuration and it appears to be working correctly on a Nexus 5 and a Kindle Fire 1st Gen.

What I am wondering is would my current library work if it were in the armeabi directory instead of the armeabi-v7a directory? I was not able to find sufficient information as to whether it matters if the OpenSSL is built with armv7 but my project libraries are built with older arm in mind.

Note: My minimum API level is 8.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What I am wondering is would my current library work if it were in the armeabi directory instead of the armeabi-v7a directory?

I think there are a couple questions here. First, can you put `libssl` and `libcrypto` in `armeabi/`. That's an Android question (not an OpenSSL question). I seem to recall Brian talking about this on the NDK mailing list (but I can't find it at the moment). I believe the idea is `armeabi/` is a fallback *if* a more specific library is not found in, for example, `armeabi-v7a/`.

Second is, can you run ARMv7a version of `libssl` and `libcrypto` on other platforms. I believe ARMv7a added a few hypervisor extensions over ARMv7, so you should be OK since OpenSSL does not use them. However, you might find yourself in trouble if running on an older device with ARMv6 or ARMv5.

In this case, you might want to download an older version of the Android NDK that builds for ARMv5, and then place ARMv5 version of `libssl` and `libcrypto` in `armeabi/`. You can find older versions of the NDK at [Android NDK](http://developer.android.com/tools/sdk/ndk/index.html) about a third of the way down the page.

To be more specific, Android 2.2 is API 8, and it was released around May 2010. So you might want to fetch and build with Android NDK Revision 3 from March 2010. NDK R3 only supported `armeabi` and targeted ARMv5TE (from the `CPU-ARCH-ABIS.TXT` file). The download is http://dl.google.com/android/ndk/android-ndk-r3-linux-x86.zip.

---

OpenSSL does not follow the instructions at [Standalone Toolchain](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/ndk/+/ics-mr0/docs/STANDALONE-TOOLCHAIN.html) for ARMv7a. Its missing the `-mfloat-abi=softfp` flag. You might have trouble calling a function that passes a float to the library from Java. There are not many of them, but one is [`RAND_add`](http://www.openssl.org/docs/crypto/RAND_add.html). The entropy estimate is passed as a float and after the incompatibility, your estimate will likely be 0.0f. See [Hard-float and JNI](http://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/android-ndk/NbUq9FDDZOo/TJJsAS6nM7wJ) on the NDK mailing list and [[Bug #3080]: Android NEON and CFLAGS options](http://rt.openssl.org/Ticket/Display.html?id=3080).

---

Here's a note from the README's that you should also be aware of:

```
  III.3. Automatic extraction of native code at install time:
  -----------------------------------------------------------

    When installing an application, the package manager service will scan
    the .apk and look for any shared library of the form:

         lib/<abi>/lib<name>.so

    If one is found, then it is copied under $APPDIR/lib/lib<name>.so,
    where $APPDIR corresponds to the application's specific data directory.
```

If you update the APK and nothing changes, then be sure to delete anything under `lib\` or delte the APK first (they have a tendency to become "sticky").

---

Another issue you will likely encounter is building and compiling against 1.0.1. Be sure you provide a wrapper shared object with a different name. Otherwise, you will likely link against 0.9.8 at runtime, and not the 1.0.1 gear in your APK. That's because Zygote loads Android's version of OpenSSL, and that version is 0.9.8. Later, when Zygote forks to create your process, the link-loader will not map-in your version of OpenSSL because its already present from Zygote.

---

> OpenSSL has 2 Android build options: android-armv7 and android-x86

I added `android-x86` to the script in June 2014. I was able to get through the build with one patch: [[Bug #3398] PATCH: fix broken compile on android-x86 with no-comp configure option](http://www.mail-archive.com/openssl-dev@openssl.org/msg34923.html). I don't have an x86 Android device, so I was not able to run the self tests on a device. Feedback is welcomed.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. As a follow-up, is there a way to compile OpenSSL 1.0.1i for armv5TE? Looking at the configurations and the instructions I linked in the original question I seem to only be able to compile for armv7 and x86.

Comment: I was able to find the solution after searching the configurations for a while. Solution to those who may run into my problem is to bypass the config and use the Configure with android option. So './Configure android $OPTIONS'